# Sharing files from Ubuntu to Mac

Tags: macos, ubuntu, ssh, network-shares, ubuntu-10.04

We're running Ubuntu 10.04 in one office and we want a couple of Mac's in another office to be able to connect to shares on this computer. We want a fairly simple solution to this if one exists. We started looking at setting up a VPN using PPTP but it seems quite complicated.  I've also seen mention of VNC, but this seems more related to sharing desktops.

All I want to do is share a directory. Can I just install OpenSSH and have the Mac users mount a share over SSH using public/private key encryption?

Comment: by "one office" and "another office" are we talking about two different rooms in the same building (presumably on the same LAN), or two different buildings (not on the same LAN)?  your mention of VPN suggests the latter, but you know what they say about assumptions.

Comment: 2 different buildings in different cities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sFTP would do for you if it's accessed on a remote network: http://blog.markvdb.be/2009/01/sftp-on-ubuntu-and-debian-in-9-easy.html

If on the same network, set up sharing on Ubuntu and MacOS: https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/opensource/?p=173

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply right-clicking on the folder (on ubuntu) and selecting Share?